# I need help converting a .blend to a .mp4

Tags: file-format

So I made a 2d animation in blender 2.8/9 and I don't know how to save it as an mp4 so I can send it to my client.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Outliner- Output Settings, in Dimension Settings choose your resolution (1080p comes by default) you can choose what frame to start or end, choose where to save in the Output section, in File Format choose FFmpeg video, in Encoding choose MPEG4 as your File Format, choose other options like quality there as well, now press ctrl+F12, or go to render - render animation, another window will pop up, wait till it's over and voila!